# Sorting an array using usort and a dynamic generated function

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I am using php function usort to sort an array. The custom php function must be generated because its dynamic

```
$intCompareField = 2;
$functSort = function($a, $b) {
  return ($a[$intCompareField] > $a[$intCompareField])?1:-1;
}

usort($arrayToSort, $functSort);
```

The `$intCompareField` in the compare function is null, my guessing is because the `$intCompareField` was declared outside of the function. Setting `global $intCompareField` does not seem to work.

Ps: I am using `$intCompareField` because the array to sort is multidimensional and i want to be able what key in the array to sort.

Comment: Are you sure you want to only ever return `1` or `-1`, it is generally desired to return `0` for "equal" values.

Comment: I know that but i want to keep the function short. Thanks tough for the comment

Comment: So, you prefer *short and broken* over *short* —though not as short as before— *and working*?  Good luck with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `use`, which passes variables from the outer scope to anonymous functions

```
function($a, $b) use ($intCompareField) {
     return ($a[$intCompareField] > $a[$intCompareField])?1:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While [Dor Shemer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9000037/113938) would suffice, I find it often better to have a function which generates the required comparison function.

```
$functSort = function ($field) {
    return function($a, $b) use ($field) {
        // Do your comparison here
    };
};

$intCompareField = 2;
usort($arrayToSort, $functSort($intCompareField));
```

You could make the function in `$functSort` be a named function (e.g. `sort_by_field_factory()` or some other appropriate name), there's no requirement for it to be an anonymous function.